# Firebase onChildEventListener slow

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using an onChildEventListener to retrive 10'000 children.
The time it takes to complete the operation is around 5 seconds.
During that time, the app freezes.
Is there a way to make it faster?
Also, I tried to use a ValueEventListener and found that cycling through children is way faster. Anyway, that wasn't a reliable solution, so I switched back to onChildEventListener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data retrieval process is exactly the same whether you use a `ValueEventListener` or a `ChildEventListener`. The only difference is in how the events are raised/callbacks are fired in your app. In addition: all network activity to the database happens on a separate thread.

This means it is not the retrieval of the data that freezes your app, but more likely the way you handle the data in your `onDataChange()` callback. If you're doing substantial work there, you'll want to do so off the main thread.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  
There were in fact two things that caused the slowness.   
I was using dataSnapshot.getValue() multiple times inside onChildAdded() and I was using notifyDataSetChanged() for every child added.
The problem i'm facing now is that I need to update the UI when all the children have been retrived. Anyway there seems to be no method built in Firebase to know when that happened.